# Bluetooth stopped working on lumia 925

Tags: 8.1, bluetooth, lumia-925

Since a week or two my bluetooth stopped working (after I cleared out my list of known devices).
The phone doesn't find any bluetooth device, it just keeps showing the "Searching..." screen.

I've done a factory reset, but that didn't help.
I've reset my phone from 8.1 Developer preview to 8, back to a full 8.1 and it is still not working.
Seeing that I got it working previously, I'm hesitant to send it back though.

Does anyone know how I could get my BT working again?

Edit:
After keeping the "Searching..." screen on for more than 15 minutes, I sometimes see other devices for a few seconds. This is not usable either.

Edit 2:
Sent it back to the shop and will have to wait a couple of weeks. Let's hope it gets fixed..

Comment: have you try to discover your lumia with another phone?

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto Yes, with both a different phone and with a computer. My lumia does not get found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the **Bluetooth module** inside your phone, which might have been damaged. Changing the module to a new one should do the trick.

Comment: How would one go about changing the Bluetooth module?

Comment: @Indrek Most likely sending it in for repairs.

Comment: Yup that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but last time my phone had an issue a.k.a. it bricked during a reset process. I just walked in to Microsoft store (since I bought my phone there) and got a new phone, because they couldn't fix it on the spot.
If that's not an option, I would try to reach out to Microsoft over phone/chat or to the manufacturer. Sims like this is not a common issue, so maybe they can help you out.

Hope that help a bit.

Comment: Yes, I'm going back to the shop tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things, best advice is take it back to a Microsoft Store and they can take it from there or call up the carrier you bought it from and see if they can organise a replacement.